# Retrieve API JSON (https) with VB.NET (ERROR: Canceled the request: Unable to create a secure SSL / TLS channel)

Tags: vb.net, api, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to query an API from my vb.net code but at the time of executing the "GetResponse" it gives the error "**Canceled the request: Unable to create a secure SSL / TLS channel**"

I have modified many things of the code tried to solve my problem but nothing works ...

I attach the code that I have to see if someone can fix it

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/1917/departing/2018/11/19?appId=583f892b&appKey=e960901ec7dcb40321306743b7a364d0")
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.UserAgent = "Test"

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim response_stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream

    Dim stream_reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(response_stream)
    Dim Data As String = stream_reader.ReadToEnd
    stream_reader.Close()

    MsgBox(Data)
```

_

```
Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

In the code you have the address of the api tal as I want to consult it

Comment: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is not even necesary for this site. Setting the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, as the answer proposes, is instead mandatory. I would use a real `UserAgent` header in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before your request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```